# Proof by mathematical induction that expression is divisible by expression,

Tags: induction

The question is : Prove by mathematical induction that :

$$
a^{2n-1} + b^{2n+1}
$$

is divisible by $$a+b$$

I've done a lot of stuff but can't put them down in tex properly. Thanks.

Comment: Then at least explain what your work is. Your question is too vague.

Comment: How is it "too vague"?

Comment: If you have "done a lot of stuff", then probably you don't need a generic hint, but something more specific. If you neither show nor explain your first results, we can't distinguish your question from the one of somebody who (for example) didn't understand induction at all and couldn't even start a solution. Then our advice won't be so effective as it could be.

Comment: That's true. True. I need something specific. My understanding isn't well grounded.

Comment: Is that supposed to be $a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}$ instead of $a^{2n-1}+b^{2n+1}$, perhaps?

Comment: @CameronBuie Nope.

Comment: @Mob The exponents must be equal else it is false, e.g. for $\rm\:n=1,\ a=2=b,\ a^{2n-1}\!+b^{2n+1} = 10\:$ is not divisible by $\rm\:a+b = 4.\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

Write it as

$$a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}=(a^2+b^2)(a^{2n-1}+b^{2n-1})-a^2b^2(a^{2n-3}+b^{2n-3})$$ and then use induction on $n$.

Comment: Thanks please, I don't understand.

Comment: +1: Mob, you'll actually be using a *strong* induction on $n$. Show that your proposition holds for $n=1,n=2$, and then you'll use the above expression to show that if $a+b$ divides $$a^{2n-3}+b^{2n-3}=a^{2(n-2)+1}+b^{2(n-2)+1}$$ and $$a^{2n-1}+b^{2n-1}=a^{2(n-1)+1}+b^{2(n-1)+1},$$ then it divides $a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}$.

Answer (score 3):

A mild variant of the answer by dmm:
$$a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}=(a+b)(a^{2n}+b^{2n})-ab(a^{2n-1}+b^{2n-1}).$$

Then directly from $a+b$ divides $a^{2k-1}+b^{2k-1}$ we can conclude that $a+b$ divides $a^{2k+1}+b^{2k+1}$. This may feel more comfortably familiar.

**Added:** In answer to a comment, the OP has indicated that $a^{2n-1}+b^{2n+1}$, which looked like an obvious typo, is not. If so, the conjectured result is false. Let $a=2$, $b=3$, $n=1$.

Answer (score 3):

By induction $\rm\:(-b)^{2n-1}\! = - b^{2n-1}$ so $\rm\:mod\ a\!+\!b\!:\ a\equiv-b\:\Rightarrow\:a^{2n-1}\!\equiv(-b)^{2n-1}\!\equiv {-}b^{2n-1}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\forall\,n\in\Bbb N\,\,\,,\,\,a^{2n+1}+b^{2n+1}=(a+b)(a^{2n}-a^{2n-1}b+....-ab^{2n-1}+b^{2n})$$

Formally, the above *still* requires a little proof by induction.